# Convert manager.dict() to list of tuples of form [[a,b,c],[q,w,e],[e,r,t].......]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to increase the computation speed of my program for which I used

```
manager=Manager()   
parallel_array_sites=manager.dict()
find_sites()
removal()
```

find_sites function is running properly

my removal function is

```
global array_sites  
for i in parallel_array_sites:
    array_sites.append(i)

#----not very relevant from here on-----

count = 0
remove_sites = {} # dictionary which contains index to remove sites
for i in range(len(array_sites)):
    remove_sites[i] = 0
for i in range(len(array_sites)): 
    if remove_sites[i]:
        continue   
    for j in range(len(array_sites)):
        if(j > i and remove_sites[j] == 0):
            x = array_sites[i][0] - array_sites[j][0]
            y = array_sites[i][1] - array_sites[j][1]
            z = array_sites[i][2] - array_sites[j][2] 
            r = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)
            if(r < (rmin/1.1)):
                count = count + 1
                remove_sites[j] = 1
print "after removel",len(array_sites)
#print remove_sites             

count = 0
for key,val in remove_sites.iteritems():
    if(val == 1):
        del array_sites[key-count]
        count = count + 1
```

The removal function requires me to use the tuples stored in

parallel_array_sites

as tuples in the list

array_sites

All the objects in parallel_array_list are tuples of 3 elements each
The number of entries can be fairly large which is why i don't want to specify the size while declaring a multiprocessing.list() instead.

The loop

```
for i in parallel_array_sites:
    array_sites.append(i)
```

does not work and gives the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 774, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
KeyError: 1081
```

Require help with any kind of changes I can make

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SamChats the for loop in function removal doesn't work due to conversion errors. i'll update the same in the question

Comment: [Edit] your Questions code up to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used

```
for i in range(len(parallel_array_sites)):
     array_sites.append(parallel_array_sites[i])
```

instead because

```
for i in parallel_array_sites:
```

does not work for a dictionary